# How to interpret an "SFC /VERIFYONLY" CBS integrity log (win10)?

Tags: logging, data-integrity

I ran an SFC on my system and it tells me that there were some "Integrity Violations" and to see the log file for more details. So I was able to open it up in Notepad, but I have no idea what I'm looking at.

Anybody have an idea?

Ross

Comment: Your question is sort of vague.

Comment: Even if I squint, I can't quite make out what the log says from here.  Could you add some sample content to your question?

Comment: In all 7megs of its glory,  http://www.nhtf.net/CBS.txt

Comment: It has been over five months since I last posted my query regarding this matter. Is it an impossible question to answer? (I have since renamed the file on the server, to http://www.nhtf.net/CBS.LOG It's now smaller, weighing in at "only" 4 megs)